# Is the random nature of quantum mechanics what creates new entropy?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, information

So I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/sMb00lz-IfE?t=344) and found what I think is a really compelling idea, and I would like to know how accurate, if at all, it is.

The point Derek makes, if I understood it correctly, is this:

1. In the context of classical mechanics, if one could know the position, momentum, charge, and a few more things, of every particle in the Universe, one could predict with certainty the future. Then one would be Laplace's Demon. This means nothing really *is* random, we model as random things that are too complex to describe in any other way, such as human behavior arising from zillions of particles interacting in very complex structures.
2. This would mean that information in the universe is constant, because you need a finite, unchaning amount of information (variables) to describe the state of the universe at any point in time. Since entropy is equivalent with information, this would mean that entropy is constant in time.
3. Nevertheless, this is not what we observe in our universe. Entropy always increases. Hence, Laplace's Demon is false. Something is creating information in the universe; there's something unpredictable that does't allow for the state of the whole universe right now to account for the state of the universe an instant later.
4. So one of the hypothesis must be wrong. Derek argues that it is the very first line of the first point: classical mechanics isn't the whole story. Quantum mechanics is fundamentally random, unpredictable, which means that it puts information into the system, because there are things which could not have been predicted from past information. Maybe it is the act of making a quantum measurement and collapsing the wave function what generates new information.

Does any of this make any sense? It sounds pretty but not very rigorous. I can think of a few objections I will list with the matching point number:

2. To me, this seems to be the most questionable point. Entropy is always tricky and the link between thermodynamic entropy and information always seems to be the most tricky of all.
3. I would argue that the logic is flawed because the universe might be infinite, in which case it would't be possible to track every possible particle. Or at least, the amount of information would be infinite, so if infinite information increases, it still is infinite and it could be said that it is constant (infinity is always tricky too). One final objection I can think of, is that if the universe is infinite, then can it be said that entropy increases? 2nd law of thermodynamics requires that the system is isolated. Can an unbound system be isolated? Does it even make sense? It cannot interact with other systems, there aren't any, it is everything in the universe together.

Comment: Entropy increases also in the classical context. The key is the fundamental postulate. Of course, this postulate is at odds with having all informations on the microstate. Notice also that there is no proof of the second law, i.e. it's an empirical law. So do not expect to prove it using QM.

Comment: "Entropy is equivalent with information" - this statement is also flawed. https://schneider.ncifcrf.gov/information.is.not.uncertainty.html

Comment: Landau discusses a possible connection between wavefunction collapse and the second law in the book *Statistical Physics*, chap. 1. You may find that interesting.